# Install Debian on MacBook Pro Late 2013 with pure EFI

Tags: linux, usb, debian, macbook-pro, efi

I resized the OSX partition. I installed rEFInd from within OSX. rEFInd works fine. When I try to install debian from the netinstaller, I have the problem, that I cant get up the ethernet interface. The Installer prompts for a driver choice, but I cant select any of them because the choice is simply not accepted. The full DVD gets somehow not accepted at all as bootable device. Neither rEFInd nor the Apple firmware (holding alt at boot) detect the bootable usb stick. I created the usb stick with `sudo dd bs=1048576 if=/<PATH>/debian-7.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/disk1` under OSX. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You must copy debian image to whole device (will be wasted for this only), not to partition.

If you want to copy it to partition, use this procedure: http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/Debian_Installer_USB_partitioning/

Comment: Although this link might contain the answer please put all information relating to the answer in the answer to avoid link rot